# Maximum Gnuttela Query Depth

Tags: calculus, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

So, I'm working through this practice exam in my data communication class. Then I never wanted to relive my calculus two days, but here we are. I think I'm dealing with an arithmetic/geometric sequence.

The original problem states:

> Consider a query flooding in a P2p Gnutella network. Suppose that each
>   peer is connected to at most $N$ neighbors in the overlay network. Also,
>   suppose that the node count field is initially set to $k$. Suppose Alice
>   makes a query Find an upper bound on the number of query messages that
>   are sent into the overlay network.

My reasoning is that something like this is going on.
Suppose $K=7$ and $x = 3$ meaning that each peer has 3 leaves, or child nodes.

The first query executes on the parent node so,
1 
Next query $k = k - 1$
$1 + (3)1$
Then
$1 + (3)1 + 9(1)$

Not sure how to produce a formula to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Having $N$ neighbours and up to $k$ hops we get for the number of query messages
\begin{align}
q_0 &= 1 \\
q_1 &= 1 + N \\
q_2 &= 1 + N + N^2 \\
\vdots \\
q_k &= \sum_{j=0}^k N^j = \frac{N^{k+1} - 1}{N - 1}
\end{align}
which is a geometric series.